# Multiple hosting views, each with a different graph/chart

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I have a ScatterPlot displayed within a CPHostingView which takes up the bottom 25% of the screen (the hosting view is 320x100).

Now i would like to display a Pie chart at the top of the view (maybe 50x50, roughly).

What do i need to do to make this possible?
My research suggests that i shouldnt create multiple instance of CPXYGraph and that i should just use multiple CPHostingViews.

Problem is, my hosting views do not take up the entire screen, thus, im having trouble determining how to render a pie-chart in one view and a scatterplot in the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use multiple hosting views.

The Core Plot hosting view is a subclass of UIView on iOS. It inherits the standard view layout mechanism from UIView. Set the autoresizingMask in code or in Interface Builder.